# How can I fix the error syntaxe SQL with DELETE function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I initialize my database with PDO and i use this parameter :

```php
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8",
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
```

I do a sql request to my Database like that :

```php
$sql = $db->query("DELETE FROM :equipement WHERE ID = :id", [
    ':equipement' => $_POST['type'],
    ':id' => (int)$_POST['id']
]);
```

var_dump($_POST) :

`array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" ["type"]=> string(8) "portable" ["action"]=> string(6) "delete" }`

my error :

`Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064`

I think my error syntaxe is :equipement because it is remplacing by 'portable' and ' create trouble...

Did you know, what i'm supposed to do to fix it?

Comment: What error do you get? How do you initialize `$db` variable?

Comment: please, post your problem with specific explanation for you issue

Comment: Sorry, i update my post with more informations

Comment: try to run this on you database direct and display the error to us.

Comment: @Faesal , On my database (phpmyadmin) I don't have error, that work

Comment: You can not bind your table name as a parameter. Check this question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter

Comment: Oh, I did not know that… Thanks, everyone, for your answer!